# Locked desfire card and ndef messages Android

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to create an Android application that handles the desfire cards. I have implemented some methods that let my authenticate, create applications etc. Until now all the communication with the card is done using the IsoDep object and the `tranceive()` command. I know that the desfire is an Nfc Forum Type 4 tag so it's supports the Ndef message structure, I have also read AN11004.

As far as I know I could communicate with the desfire, if it was not protected with a password, with the Ndef Object of Android API. How will I communicate with the locked desfire card? I know that first the authentication, select application etc. procedures will be done with IsoDep object, after that how will I manipulate with the ndef messages?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: +1 That's a lot of terms i'm unfamiliar with in a single Android question.

Answer (score 0):

> How will I communicate with the locked desfire card?

Unless you know the 'unlocking'-key of the card, you can not do much with it. You will always be able to detect it, you will always be able to try to authenticate with it (will fail, because the DESfire is locked).

That's it.

For ordinary DESFire: Alll keys can be cracked within a day with a side-channel attack (needs specialized hardware). For DESFire EV-1 Tags no crack is known so far.

Comment: I think you meant to say "For ordinary [Mifare Classics]: [not Mifare Desfire] all keys can be cracked within a day". If you really did mean Mifare Desfire, then I'd love to get a citation for that.

Comment: First of all thanks for your time! I know the desfire key, i just want  to know if i could use for example the Ndef Object so i could easily transfer data to the card or i have to use the native methods like `WriteData() `.

Comment: The crack was presented at the 29C3 conference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y1o2ST03O8I#t=1501s